# Yellowing salvia greggii

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health

I bought an autumn sage a few days ago, it had a few yellow leaves on the bottom but it seemed fine.

However now there's yellowing and browning in the flowers too and a lot of the bottom leaves have fallen off.

The plant came in a small pot and I've only watered it once in the three days that I've had it.

I was waiting for it to get acclimatized before moving it to a bigger pot, right now I keep it in a bright spot where it gets some early morning sunshine.

Could it be a fungal problem or is it something else?
[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

They are multiple reasons why a plant can have yellowing on the leaves. Depending on location could be weather change, humidity, not enough water, too much water and just overall stress. It doesn't look like its a disease or fungus. It could be that the plant did not get enough sun and water before you bought it and now you are seeing more results. I would change to a bigger pot or add more potting soil to cover more the sensible areas.

https://www.pennington.com/all-products/fertilizer/resources/why-plant-leaves-turn-yellow-and-how-to-fix-them